# When I retrieve data in json I am not able to get my local lingual instead I am getting unicode

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, unicode

I storing unicode tamil character in database  I am trying to retrieve it using php an display in browser. I am putting it to in array and get it in json.
I a am getting the following output

```
{
"product_id":"29",
"download_id":"ebbe8e1e1f4649bb8a51468828100d91",
"order_key":"wc_order_5492e914ee249",
"post_title":"\u0ba4\u0bae\u0bbf\u0bb4\u0bcd \u0bae\u0bc2\u0bb2\u0bbf\u0b95\u0bc8\u0b95\u0bb3\u0bcd \u0b89\u0ba3\u0bb5\u0bc1\u0b95\u0bc1\u0b95\u0bb3\u0bcd",
"status":"true"
}
```

I am using the following code,

```
$sql = "SELECT wdp.product_id, wdp.download_id, wdp.order_key, wp.post_title
FROM product_permissions wdp, posts wp
WHERE wdp.user_email =  'testemail@gmail.com'
AND wdp.product_id = wp.ID";

$result = mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );      
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$int_num_field = mysql_num_fields($result);     
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){       
     $arr_col = array();
     for($i=0;$i<$int_num_field;$i++){
         echo $row[$i];
         $arr_col[mysql_field_name($result,$i)] = $row[$i];
     }
     $arr_col['status']= 'true';
     array_push($json,$arr_col);        
}       
array_push($person,$json);
$main = array('products'=>$json);
echo json_encode($main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
`echo json_encode($main,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

In php 5.4+, php's json_encode does have the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option for plain output. On older php versions, you can roll out your own JSON encoder that does not encode non-ASCII characters, or use [Pear's](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download) JSON encoder.

**EDIT**

or you can try this function

```
function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
   return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($struct));
}
```

[source](http://www.avoid.org/replace-u-characters-in-json-string/)

Comment: thanks, I am sorry to say that when I tried above suggestion all I received was "{"product_id":"29","download_id":"ebbe8e1e1f4649bb8a51468828100d91","order_key":"wc_order_5492e914ee249","post_title":"à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®®à¯‚à®²à®¿à®•à¯ˆà®•à®³à¯ à®‰à®£à®µà¯à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯","status":"true"}" Please let me know any other solution, I want receive it in Tamil (Indian Local Lingua )

Comment: Yes I tried but output is, "{\"product_id\":\"29\",\"download_id\":\"ebbe8e1e1f4649bb8a51468828100d91\",\"order_key\":\"wc_order_5492e914ee249\",\"post_title\":\"\u0ba4\u0bae\u0bbf\u0bb4\u0bcd \u0bae\u0bc2\u0bb2\u0bbf\u0b95\u0bc8\u0b95\u0bb3\u0bcd \u0b89\u0ba3\u0bb5\u0bc1\u0b95\u0bc1\u0b95\u0bb3\u0bcd\",\"status\":\"true\"}"

Comment: Yes I am storing tamil character in database(MySql)

Comment: Sorry patel for late comment echo json_encode($main,JSON_INESCAPED_UNICODE); is worked fine , I missed header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');